# This one's for Matthew:

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, cryptic-clues

> I tend nations damaged, with many a crater
>   Spilt blood, nothing lost! That's a strong indicator
>   Reason's right if I act; out something charged!
>   Rounds for the charger, allows losing large...

With all my skills, what can I change?

> <sub>12:4-13:7</sub>

<sub>EDIT: appropriate tags added post-solve:</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lines are

> Cryptic crossword clues

I tend nations damaged, with many a crater

> INDENTATIONS

Spilt blood, nothing lost! That's a strong indicator

> BOLD

Reason's right if I act; out something charged!

> JUSTIFICATION

Rounds for the charger, allows losing large...

> BULLETS

With all my skills, what can I change?

> the formatting?

Comment: wow... nice job +1...

Comment: _That's_ more like it. (I had the first line but no more, but that was enough to convince me that the other two answers were on the wrong track...)

Comment: Bull for charger? Is that kosher?

Comment: Yup. If it were a hog, it wouldn't be. :-)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the enumerations.

Comment: Correct!  For completion's sake, rot13("Sbe Znggurj" -> "Sbezng"  naq gur ahzoref ng gur obggbz jrer gur rahzrengvbaf sbeznggrq nf ovoyr irefrf sbe n erq ureevat)  Excellent job

Comment: Fun and apropos fact: my name is Matthew.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: you are

> Jesus

You can change

> anything I suppose?

With partial explanation

I tend nations damaged, with many a crater

> Perhaps Crater is referring to the parable of the sower about grains? [starting from Matthew 13:1]

Spilt blood, nothing lost! That's a strong indicator

> Jesus healing people

Reason's right if I act; out something charged!

> Jesus charging out demons (a kindly deed, that's the reason) [starting from Matthew 12:22]

Hint:

> Refers to [Matthew 12:4-13:7 of the Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2012&version=NIV)

Comment: It's a plausible enough conjecture and I wondered the same thing. But none of the lines actually seem to me to fit very well -- and if that really is a bible reference then it's a strange one -- it starts and ends in mid-speech and what's in between covers a fair bit of ground.

Comment: I have a different conjecture at what sort of thing is going on here, and suspect that the thing above is a red herring. But my own conjecture is no more than quarter-baked so far, if even that.

Answer (score 2):

Omega Krypton has the right person,

> Jesus is the person being referenced.

With all of your posts, you can change

> Water into Wine, one of His Biblical Miracles.

Comment: he can change a lot of things, why this in particular?

Comment: This is one of the classical changes that He did.

Comment: it turns out that we're both wrong xD